# jinja2 yaml python hash issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a problem with jinja

generate.py:

```
from jinja2 import Template  
import yaml  
import sys  
import os.path

#Parse the YAML file and produce a Python dict.
yaml_vars = yaml.load(open('parameters.yaml').read())

#Load the Jinja2 template into a Python data structure.
template = Template(open('skel.j2').read())

#Render the configuration using the Jinja2 render method using yaml_vars as arg.
rendered_config = template.render(yaml_vars)

#Write the rendered configuration to a text file.
with open('config.txt', 'w') as config:  
    config.write(rendered_config)
```

parameters.yaml

```
city : LA
```

skel.j2 without any problems

```
123qwe
```

skel.j2 with a problem

```
{{
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate.py", line 10, in <module>
    template = Template(open('skel.j2').read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 945, in __new__
    return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 880, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<unknown>", line 2, in template
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected end of template, expected 'end of print statement'.
```

Q: how can I disable processing for string '{{' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in [the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#escaping), the easiest way of getting `{{` in your output is to actually print it:

```
{{ '{{' }}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use a `raw` block:

```
{% raw %}
    {{
{% endraw %}
```